# Symfony2 yml: Passing same parameter to each service

Tags: symfony, service, yaml

I'm trying to reuse [@service_container,@doctrine.orm.entity_manager] as a single variable but can't seem to figure it out.  I plan to reuse when adding more models.

```
services:
    generalfunctions:
        class: classes\classBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    functionsClass:
        class: classes\classBundle\Classes\functionsClass    
        arguments:    [@service_container,@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    OtakuClass:
        class: classes\classBundle\Models\otakusModel
        arguments:    [@service_container,@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Comment: You may want take a look to the [auto wiring](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-service-auto-wiring) feature of sy

Comment: Parent services might also be a viable approach: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html.  Does seem very strange to pass both the container as well as the entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- not bother
- pass only service container and get all services from it
- create own class that contains only repeating services and methods **getServiceContainer()**, **getEntityManager()**, etc
- use autowire - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/autowiring.html

Comment: Opps, should have known I could get the entity manager from the service container

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone I ended up making a base class and all the models extend that single base class.  I didn't know you could just copy the entity manager from the service object.

```
<?php
namespace classes\classBundle\Models;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
class baseModel
{
    protected $container;
    protected $user;
    protected $functionsClass;
    protected $em;
    protected $connection;
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $this->container->get("doctrine")->getManager();
        $this->connection =  $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');
        $this->functionsClass = $this->container->get("functionsClass");
        $this->user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}

<?php
namespace classes\classBundle\Models;
use classes\classBundle\Models\baseModel;
use classes\classBundle\Entity\subscriptions;
class subscriptionsModel extends baseModel
{
    public function returnSubscription($params)
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('classesclassBundle:subscriptions');
        $subscription =  $repository->findBy($params);
        return $subscription;
    }
    public function subscribe($params)
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('classesclassBundle:subscriptions');
        $params['otakuid'] = $this->container->get("OtakuClass")->getId();
        $subscription =  $repository->findOneBy($params);
        if ($subscription == null)
        {
            $subscription = new subscriptions();
            foreach ($params as $key => $value)
            $subscription->$key = $value;
            $this->em->persist($subscription);
        }
        else
        $this->em->remove($subscription);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}

services:
    generalfunctions:
     class: classes\classBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    functionsClass:
     class: classes\classBundle\Classes\functionsClass    
     arguments:    [@service_container]
    OtakuClass:
     class: classes\classBundle\Models\otakusModel
     arguments:    [@service_container]
    privateMessagesModel:
     class: classes\classBundle\Models\privateMessagesModel
     arguments:    [@service_container]
    subscriptionsModel:
     class: classes\classBundle\Models\subscriptionsModel
     arguments:    [@service_container] 
    otakusImagesModel:
     class: classes\classBundle\Models\otakusImagesModel
     arguments:    [@service_container]  
    categoriesModel:
     class: classes\classBundle\Models\categoriesModel
     arguments:    [@service_container]
    forumsModel:
     class: classes\classBundle\Models\forumsModel
     arguments:    [@service_container]
```